# Are my Variables in JS null? Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, null

I'm actually working to display a location using Google Maps API. But the values of the latitudes and longitude are taken from a table in my database.mdf file and then parsed into 2 HiddenFields respectively.

I would like to ask with the way i'm writing the codes, are the values null?

I have not much experience with JavaScript..

Pictures/Codes to illustrate at the bottom..

From my page.aspx.cs file, i'm setting the HiddenFields value to be latitude and longitude respectively.

```
foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            accountDB = r["AccountStatus"].ToString();
            latitudeDB = Convert.ToDouble(r["Latitude"]);
            longitudeDB = Convert.ToDouble(r["Longitude"]);
            usernameDB = r["Username"].ToString();
            ipDB = r["IPAddressOfCreation"].ToString();
        }
HF_Latitude.Value = latitudeDB.ToString();
        HF_Longitude.Value = longitudeDB.ToString();
```

Codes under script tag in page.aspx

```
<div id="generatedMap" style="width: 525px; height: 300px; background-color: grey;"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function initMap() {
                        var latitudeDB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%= HF_Latitude.ClientID %>").value);
                        var longitudeDB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%= HF_Longitude.ClientID %>").value);

                        var mapProp = {
                            zoom: 15,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeDB, longitudeDB),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                        };

                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("generatedMap"), mapProp);

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeDB, longitudeDB),
                            map: map,
                            title: "<div style = 'height:50px;width:120px'><b>Consumer's location:</b><br />Latitude: " + latitudeDB + "<br />Longitude: " + longitudeDB,
                        });
                    }
                </script>
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

The values that i parse into the class new.google.maps.Latlng(latitude, and longitude), are these 2 values null? I can't seem to make the Google Maps appear..

The coordinates stored in my database are of float datatype.

Comment: Could it be if (latitudeHF.value != null) latitude = latitudeHF.value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. In html you are setting div `class` as attributes and in java-script you are retrieving as `Id` attributes so that's the problem google map is not appearing.

**Instead of :**

```
<div class="generatedMap"></div>
```

**Should be :**

```
<div id="generatedMap"></div>
```

**Javascript code will remain as it is. if you wanted to keep class as it is then use blow code in javascript**

**Instead of :**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('generatedMap')
```

**Should be :**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('generatedMap')
```

And make sure that from server-side lat & lng values are coming in hidden variables.

Comment: First of all i am not sure that how to get server side variable value in js file.I think you are using .net framework.So please can you store this value and just put those 2 variables in alert/console so you will get better idea. If you are getting values of lat & lng then are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Will try that immediately. Im actually retrieving 2 values from my database lat and lng respectively, then storing them into 2 hiddenfields separately..

Comment: Ok so you are creating 2 hidden variables in 1 page and then after are you able to getting this variables value or not?

Comment: i just tried using Debug.WriteLine(lat and lng accordingly), i got those 2 exact values from the database.. but i dont think it sends it to the javascript..

Comment: That's the issue from the server side just create viewBar object and in cshtml page get value like this way var temp_lat = '@ViewBag.lat';.

Comment: Some issues in line : var latitudeDB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("<%= HF_Latitude.ClientID %>").value); i mean in this code <%= HF_Latitude.ClientID %> i think wrong way that you retrieving the values.

Comment: may i ask how to do that..? i have never heard of this method before...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150604/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-domster).